# Getting the distance and the direction of the nearest detected obstacle

Tags: python, nao-robot, pepper, choregraphe

Is there a way to get the distance and the direction of the nearest detected obstacle?

I have tried with this ["Navigation/AvoidanceNavigator/ObstacleDetected"](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/motion/alnavigation-api.html#Navigation/AvoidanceNavigator/ObstacleDetected) event, but it never triggers event if I position the robot next to the wall and tell him to go 5 meters long in the wall direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no API for the "nearest obstacle, but the [ALMotion/MoveFailed](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/motion/reflexes-external-collision-api.html#ALMotion/MoveFailed) event may be what you want - it will tell you where the obstacle is and why it failed.

Answer (score 1):

During navigation you can use the [ObstacleDetected](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/motion/alnavigation-api.html?highlight=exploration#Navigation/AvoidanceNavigator/ObstacleDetected) event to notify you of obstacles. The position i given in robotframe.
You will get the x,y coordinates so you will have to calculate distance yourself.

Comment: The problem is that event does not work for my robot, or at all, don't know. I have subscribed to it as I have subscribed to all other events I use, but this one and the other from the Navigation simply never raise.

Comment: hm, have you tested the status first?
http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/motion/alnavigation-api.html#Navigation/AvoidanceNavigator/Status

Comment: Yes, same problem with this event. Actually none of the 'Navigation/AvoidanceNavigator' events works with my robot.

Comment: Unless you can find some working code sample, I think you should create a support ticket. You could ask for some guidelines of how to use the events. I haven't used them myself so I don't know what might be wrong.

Comment: I am using events all the time so I think this is problem not with the way I use/define/listen events, but the events of  the 'Navigation/AvoidanceNavigator'. Maybe I really should create  a support ticket.

Comment: Just so I don't misunderstand you; I was not accusing you of using the events wrong ;-)  There could be a bug in the navigation API.